# Ubuntu 18.04 Copy contents of multiple directories to external server

Tags: server, 18.04, delete, copy, transfer

I searched for a while and I couldn't find solution to what I want to do in Ubuntu. I have multiple directories that I want to transfer its content to external storage server and then delete them from first machine. Simply explanation:

```
S1 = Main Server
ESS = External Storage Server
S1 has approx 5 directories (there may be more in the future) that I want to transfer its content to ESS and then delete them from S1.
```

Contents of these directories are .zip files that will be copied on almost daily basis.

Comment: I would recommend rsync https://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync where you can set params as required.

Comment: @Graham Do you think this will be valid? `rsync -rt --remove-source-files root@server:{/home/example1,/etc/example2,/srv/example3} example@x.x.x.x:/storage`

Comment: I don't see why not. It appears to follow the convention mentioned here: https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-bsd-appleosx-rsync-delete-file-after-transfer/ I'd add the --dry-run option to be certain. Shall I post that as an answer for others with the same query?

Comment: Yeah, works great like that:
`rsync --remove-source-files -rte 'ssh -p23' {directory1,directory2,directory3} /mnt/share/Backups/` (i've mounted my external storage server so i could use cron to shedule it

Comment: added as an answer. Perhaps you would be kind enough to mark it up as the accepted answer so that it is easier for someone with the same question to find in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Précis of comments under the OP.

I would recommend the use of rsync where you can set parameters as required to delete source files files after a successful transfer to another volume.

Referring to rsync Linux Man page [here](https://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync) the command line `rsync --remove-source-files -rte 'ssh -p23' {directory1,directory2,directory3} /mnt/share/Backups/` works having referenced [this link](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-bsd-appleosx-rsync-delete-file-after-transfer/) which outlines the specific arrangements for deleting source files after transfer.

This can be automated of course by using a cron job to schedule it.